# Missing test case for linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a function to delete a give number from a linked list in codefights. I am passing 6 out of 7 test cases, however, the 7th is hidden so I am not able to see what it is I am doing wrong. Can anyone see what test case I am missing with this function?

```
// Definition for singly-linked list:
// template<typename T>
// struct ListNode {
//   ListNode(const T &v) : value(v), next(nullptr) {}
//   T value;
//   ListNode *next;
// };
#include <stdio.h> 
ListNode<int> * removeKFromList(ListNode<int> * l, int k) {
    ListNode<int> *cur = l;
    ListNode<int> *temp = l;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->value == k) {
            if (cur == l) {
                ListNode<int> *del;
                del = cur;
                cur = cur->next;
                l = l->next;
                temp = temp->next;
                delete del;
            } else {
                ListNode<int> *del = cur;
                cur = cur->next;
                temp->next = cur;
                delete del;
            }
        } else {
            temp = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    } 
    return l;

}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please tag your question appropriately. [c]?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but this code is overly complicated. It could be reduced to `auto pp = &l; while (*pp) { if ((*pp)->value == k) { auto tmp = *pp; *pp = (*pp)->next; delete tmp; } else { pp = &(*pp)->next; } } return l;`.

Comment: Code seems alright to me. Only issue I think is whether multiple deletes are needed in single query or not. If not then you are simply wasting the time iterating over the whole linked list